# Represent a JSON array - Android SDK

Tags: java, android, json, sdk

I have this JSON :

```
{ 
    "id" : "1405247989732",
    "title" : "פיקוד העורף התרעה במרחב ",
    "data" : [
        "באר שבע 292",
        "באר שבע 291"
    ]
}
```

(From a server)
I want to store `data` in an Array, and also refresh the JSON every 3 secs because the data array can change anytime.
Where to start?

Comment: start by going through some json parsing tutorials

Comment: Look at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it:

**A.**  Create a Java class whose fields (names and types) match your Json:

```
class MyDataRecord {
    String id;
    String title
    String[] data;
}
```

**B.**  And use [GSon](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) to read and write content from Json string to your class:

```
MyDataRecord dataRecord = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyDataRecord.class); // string to obj

String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(dataRecord); // obj to string
```

**C.**  Periodically poll you server to get updates. You can also use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) for server push, but if I understand
correctly the scope of your program, server polling will probably suffice.

Gilad

Answer (score 0):

As eluded to in the comments, there are a variety of json parsers available for Android. If your obtaining your json from a server, I would advise looking into square's Retrofit. As retrofit will not only parse the json, but also perform the http request for you as well.

```
http://square.github.io/retrofit/
```

In regards to the three second polling, you could do something like this:

```
handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        json = getJsonFromServer()

        handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
    }
};
handler.post(r);
```

This will places a runnable on your message queue, that will call the method that gets the json and then places itself on the message queue to execute again in three seconds.

While this will work, it is a much better practice to use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) server to push updates down to your phones whenever the value changes as opposed to constantly querying the server.

```
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html
```